# Jensen’s inequality in Convexity adjustment premium

Tags: bond, risk-management, convexity

[image]

[image]

I'm preparing for my FRM II test in May. Could someone help to explain where does the 0.0823 come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P_2-P_1$ where:

$P_1=\frac{1000}{\left(1+\frac{0.06+0.04}{2} \right)\left(1+0.05
\right)}$

$P_2=0.5\frac{1000}{\left(1+0.06 \right)\left(1+0.05
\right)}+0.5 \frac{1000}{\left(1+0.04 \right)\left(1+0.05
\right)}$